# Does terraform always replace a linux virtual machine when updating the admin_ssh_key public key?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to update the public_key in the admin_ssh_key block of azurerm_linux_virtual_machine which is causing terraform to trigger VM replacement. Forcing the VM replacement is causing the ip addresses to be refreshed which we don't want.

I am using terraform version 0.12.20 & provider version 2.50.0.

When I update the public_key in the main.tf, it is always forcing the VM to be replaced. When I do that (update SSH key) through portal, it doesn't replace the VM. Is this an expected behavior in terraform?

I use something like this (many details hidden as they aren't required):

```
resource "tls_private_key" "this" {
  for_each  = <Iterable list>
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 2048
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "linux_vms" {
admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "username"
    public_key = lookup(tls_private_key.this, each.key)["public_key_openssh"]
  }
}
```

Result:

```
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.linux_vms["index"] must be replaced
      - admin_ssh_key { # forces replacement
          - public_key = <<~EOT
                ssh-rsa some key 
            EOT -> null
          - username   = "username" -> null
          }
      + admin_ssh_key { # forces replacement
          + public_key = (known after apply)
          + username   = "username"
        }
```

Before I execute this, I taint the value of tls_private_key, to force replacement of the key. But, I didn't expect that the VM will be replaced.

This is being done to enforce secrets expiration as the public key is later stored in a key vault.

Comment: Yes, this happens on GCP and AWS as well. All three platforms provision SSH keys on instance creation; beyond that, you need something outside Terraform.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I thought I was doing some kind if mistake

Comment: This is subject to the limitations of the API parameters and request/response bodies. You would indeed need to work outside the Azure API to perform this modification as an Update.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it really depends on the resource type. If you want to avoid VM replacement when updating the SSH key, you might consider using the azurerm virtual machine extension resource to change the SSH key post-deployment.

Answer (score 1):

In Terraform, most providers specify what resources force replacements when changed. Unfortunately, this is mostly out of your control. In this case, [azurerm_linux_virtual_machine](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/main/website/docs/r/linux_virtual_machine.html.markdown) is replaced when `admin_ssh_key` changes.

> admin_ssh_key - (Optional) One or more admin_ssh_key blocks as defined below. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.

You should typically either make sure this resource doesn't change, or find creative ways to keep it consistent with external changes.

This case however sounds like a configuration management problem, as it involves SSH access. Configuration management tools install and manage software on a machine that already exists. Terraform is not a configuration management tool, and its strengths are in bootstrapping and initializing resources.

You should use the lifecycle management argument to ignore changes to `admin_ssh_key` and manage SSH access using a configuration management tool such as Salt. This way, each user in your organization can have SSH keys managed in a more secure, consistent and visible manner than a single key.

The admin SSH key can just be a way to get into the instance during its initial bootstrap phase, and if you ever need to recreate it.

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example" {
  # ...

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      # Ignore changes to tags, e.g. because a management agent
      # updates these based on some ruleset managed elsewhere.
      admin_ssh_key,
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like many cloud compute platforms based on virtual machines, the Azure approach to handling explicitly-configured SSH keys is to [expose a private metadata API to all virtual machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/instance-metadata-service?tabs=linux), which includes the configured SSH public keys and everything else that the system would need to self-configure during its first boot.

Software installed in your chosen machine image is then responsible for requesting that metadata document and configuring the system appropriately. The de-facto standard software for performing these configuration tasks is [CloudInit](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Because this approach requires software in the instance to "pull" metadata from this well-known API endpoint, there is no way in this protocol for the cloud platform to announce to the VM that metadata has changed. Because of that, CloudInit is typically configured to run only once during system boot, during which it will write various files to disk, including the `authorized_keys` file that the SSH server uses to know which keys are acceptable.

Because there's no way to tell a VM that its metadata has changed, the Azure API does not allow you to change the metadata once the system has started. The `hashicorp/azurerm` provider for Terraform models that situation by announcing that it can only change those arguments that are handled through the metadata service by totally replacing the VM.

---

If you want to be able to change SSH keys dynamically at runtime then you will need to build your own solution to do that.

There are two main variations of approaches for that, both of which will require additional software beyond just Terraform:

- Use traditional configuration management software to either push new configuration into a running instance over SSH or to pull new configuration using a mechanism specific to your configuration management software.

  By "traditional configuration management software" I mean the likes of Ansible, Chef, and Puppet, each of which has a slightly different model for applying changes to an already-running system.
- Change your SSH server configuration to retrieve authorized keys by requesting them from some other location dynamically, rather than by referring to a static file on disk.

  If you are using OpenSSH, you can use the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` option to tell the server to run an arbitrary program you've written each time it wants to obtain the authorized keys for a user. You can design that program to fetch the keys from some other location, although of course you will need to somehow mitigate the risk that someone could compromise that central repository of allowed keys to inject a new key that they control and thus gain access to your VMs.

---

Another option to allow for secrets rotation is to use OpenSSH *certificate-based* authentication instead of using naked keys. In that case you can issue each client a time-limited certificate signed by a carefully-controlled private key and configure your servers to trust any valid certificate signed by that central authority.

You can issue clients time-limited certificates to force them to periodically request a new certificate, without needing to change the root trusted certificate on each system. You would only need to change the configuration of your VMs if the root key is compromised.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `lifecycle` meta-argument to change that behavior.

You can consider modifying your resource like below

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "linux_vms" {
  # your resource arguments definition

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      admin_ssh_key,
    ] 
  }
}
```

For more information, visit here https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#ignore_changes

Comment: This would ignore the updates OP is trying to make, leaving the SSH key unchanged.

Comment: That's how we created it initially. I was trying to see if the ssh keys could be updated via terraform. Maybe we cannot.